# Joining the data of two table with some prior conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

There are two tables which need to combine and expand and insert according to the second table.

First table data is in week level and second data is in month level and week both, need to add col in first as same as Lock table

Note:

- column a has no dependence on calculation but its a primary key so data inserted is blank so not an issue
- b should in form in query is b like 'tri%'

Table 1 ft has data :

```
a      b            c           start       end          f        
rohit  tripathi     gj          29-05-22    31-06-22     3
rohit  triple       gj          29-06-22    04-06-22     4
rohit  triwa        gj          05-06-22    11-06-22     7
rohit  triwa        gj          12-06-22    18-06-22     7
rohit  triwa        gj          19-06-22    25-06-22     7
rohit  tritha       gj          26-06-22    30-06-22     5
rohit  triwa        th          26-06-22    02-07-22     2
```

table 2 lock has data:

```
a       b            c          start        end          L       time
        tri          gj         29-05-22     31-05-22     1       week
        tri          gj         01-06-22     30-06-22     1       month
        tri          gj         01-07-22     07-07-22     1       week
```

Data I want like in ft table:

```
a      b            c           start       end          L          Time      
rohit  tripathi     gj          29-05-22    31-05-22     1          week
rohit  triple       gj          01-06-22    04-06-22     1          month
rohit  triwa        gj          05-06-22    11-06-22     1          month 
rohit  triwa        gj          12-06-22    18-06-22     1          month 
rohit  triwa        gj          19-06-22    25-06-22     1          month
rohit  tritha       gj          26-06-22    30-06-22     1          month
rohit  triwa        th          26-06-22    02-07-22     1          week
```

Please let me know any concerns or more clearity.

Comment: Please clarify how did you match `table1` and `table2`

Comment: Yes both table 1 and table 2 is connected by start as well as with c column but with column b there we as condition only first two letter should be there like if this gjnesh then we should write b like 'gj%'

Comment: Hi - your last comment really doesn’t explain anything. Please update your question to provide a logical list of the steps that need to be followed to join the tables, an explanation for how to get the results you want having joined the tables and then provide sample data, formatted as tables, that illustrates all the possible use cases. For example, in your last comment you’ve given “gjnesh” as an example but this isn’t in your question’s example data - so your question seems to be missing at least one use case

Comment: I tried to solve it in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wKYXmgHI), but input periods in some rows are incorrect (end < start in row 2 for example) and logic is not quite clear.